# How to make custom form [type email] window

Tags: html, css

Email inputs always have a small box informing you about incorrect syntax, length etc.

Is there a way to apply custom CSS to these boxes?

Comment: add `novalidate` to the `form` html element and create your own validations

Comment: Please read **[ask]** and then update the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would debug it with developers tools and try to overwrite the class of this hint. Other way is to redefine this bootstrap(?) class in some global styles file.

Comment: its not possible, try it in chrome.

Comment: You can enforce mouse action on input element (focus i.e.) and then find the hint div inside of html. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Also if you are using some kind of themed styles, you should check it in the docs of this theme first.